# Как сохранить сгенерированный файл в выбранную директорию

Tags: java

Я новичок в данном вопросе и это моя первая программа. Пытаюсь написать небольшую программу с интерфейсом Swing. Идея - пользователь должен выбрать директорию с файлами, программа объединяет все файлы в один и предлагает скачать готовый файл. При этом пользователь должен выбрать путь сохранения, например на рабочий стол. Получилось создать готовый файл (имя - true5.txt), а как сохранить файл с выбором места не знаю. На данный момент он сохраняется в папку проекта. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
class MargeFiles implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent A) {

        JFileChooser dir = new JFileChooser();
        dir.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        dir.showSaveDialog(null);

        String someString = dir.getSelectedFile().toString();


        try
                (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("true5.txt")) {
            File f = new File(someString);

            String[] s = f.list();
            if (s == null) {
                throw new IOException("Directory doesn't exist: " + f);
            }
            for (String s1 : s) {
                File f1 = new File(f, s1);
                if (!f1.isFile()) {
                    continue;
                }
                try (Reader reader = new FileReader(f1);
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        pw.println(line);
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {

            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй использовать такой код:

```
File resultFile = new File(path + "\\result.txt");
```

где `path` - путь к директории, которую выбрал пользователь, а `result.txt` - имя сгенерированного файла.